# How can I change text in snap.svg

Tags: jquery, snap.svg

I make a drawing on a website with lines and text. i use snap.svg en JQuery.

s is the drawing surface, g a group with an id "g54".

```
g.add(s.text(120, 120, "outside").attr({    "font-size": "15px" }));
```

I want to change the text, i tried it in several ways.
I can change the place of the text, the color, but not the text itself.

```
$("#g54 text").attr({ x: 800, y: 700});
$("#g54 text").attr({ stroke: "red" });
$("#g54 text").attr({ text: "test", x: 800, y: 700 });//text doesn't work
$("#g54 text").attr({ innerHTML: "test" });   //innerHTML doesn't work
$("#g54 text").attr({ "innerHTML": "test" });   //innerHTML doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Snap, the text attribute should work.

```
var t = s.text(120, 120, "outside").attr({ "font-size": "15px" })
g.add(t)
t.attr("text","changed")
```

You can reference existing SVG elements in Snap with the Snap() method. Eg

```
Snap("#textelement").attr("text","changed")
```

So you could also try

```
Snap("#g54 text").attr("text","changed")
```

I'm not sure jquery works quite right with svg, so better to use Snap direct.

Answer (score 0):

After all, the Snap selector did it for most of the text items, but for some it didn't (I couldn't see why). So I tries it again with JQuery, and the following works.

```
JQuery("#g54").children().text("this is my text");
```